# Cannot transform the constraints into the standard form of quadratic programming problem

Tags: optimization, constraints, quadratic-programming

I'm solving a constrained optimization problem, where I have to find the vector $\mathbf{x}$ of dimensionality `N x 1`. The input vectors are $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ with dimensionality `N x 1`. The error function which I have to minimize is:

$$E(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^N(a_i-x_i)^2=(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{x})$$

I've to minimize this error function subject to $N$ constraints:

$$x_i \ge \varepsilon_i \; \; \; \; \; \; \forall i \in [1, N] $$

where $\varepsilon_i$ is defined as:

$$\varepsilon_i =\begin{cases} k &for \; i = 1\\ x_{i-1} + h_{i - 1} + \eta &for \; i \gt 1 \end{cases}$$

for some constants $k$ and $\eta$, and $h_i$ is ith value of vector $\mathbf{h}$.

So, the error function is quadratic and constraints are linear, so its a quadratic programming problem with $N$ variables to find.

The general form of the quadratic programming problem is to minimize $\mathbf{x}^TP\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{x}$ subject to the constraints $G\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{h}$.

I can easily convert the error function to this general form by computing the matrix $P$ and vector $\mathbf{q}$, as $P = I$ and $\mathbf{q} = -2\mathbf{a}$. But I'm having a lot of trouble in transforming the constraints to the general form of $G\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{h}$ as I cannot take the vector $\mathbf{x}$ on the one side of the inequalities. As $i$th value of vector $\mathbf{x}$ depend on the $i-1$th value of $\mathbf{x}$ (as $\mathbf{x}_i \ge \varepsilon_i$ and $\varepsilon_i$ depends on the value of $\mathbf{x}_{i-1}$).

Actually I have to code this problem in JavaScript, and I have found a library that provides the solution for the quadratic programming problem, but I need the matrices $P$ and $G$, and vectors $\mathbf{q}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ for that ($\mathbf{x}^TP\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{q}^T\mathbf{x}$ subject to $G\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{h}$). If I could just find the matrix $G$ and vector $\mathbf{h}$, I would just make a function call and the problem would be solved. So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first constraint is $x_1 \geq k$, i.e., $-x_1 \leq -k$

Your second constraint is $x_2 \geq x_1 + h_1 + \eta$, i.e., $x_1 -x_2 \leq -h_1 - \eta$

...and so you continue.

Hence, $G = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 \ldots \\1 & -1 & 0 \ldots\\\vdots \end{pmatrix} $ and $h = \begin{pmatrix}-k\\-h_1-\eta\\\vdots\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that doesn't help me converting them to the form of $G\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{h}$, or at least I'm stuck converting it.

Comment: made it more explicit

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Can you also confirm whether I've computed the matrix $P$ and vector $q$ correctly or not?

Comment: Since $(a-x)^T(a-x)$ expands to $a^Ta - 2a^Tx + x^Tx$ identification yields $P =I$ and $q = -2a$. Note though that many solvers and references use the standard form $\frac{1}{2}x^TQx + q^Tx$ so don't mess up on the factor $2$.

Comment: Yes, I did see that my solution for $P$ and $q$ was totally incorrect. And then I also came up with the $P=I$ and $q=-2a$, but then I wasn't sure about this solution either, because of the $a^Ta$ factor. How would $P=I$ and $q=-2a$ produce the factor $a^Ta$?

Comment: It cannot, as that form does not include any constant term (which makes no difference as it doesn't influence the choice of $x$)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much for the help Johan. Actually I'm not from Mathematics major, so pardon my nonsense. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I am working on a quadratic programming problem that I have been stuck on for 4 days. After I have rewritten the Lagrangian so that it is no longer in terms of $x$, I cannot figure out how to take the sup in order to derive the dual problem. Could you please take a look and help me? There is a 100 point bounty on the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571031/need-help-setting-up-and-solving-dual-problem